# Expected value of absolute value of trades

Tags: statistics, expectation, central-limit-theorem

Suppose each day for $365$ days, we flip a coin. If it lands heads, I get \$10. If it lands tails, I lose \$10. What is the expected value of the absolute value of the amount of money I have (or owe) after the $365$ days?

For 1 and 2 days, the answer works out to be 10. Is this always true? We may assume the CLT, but I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: No, for 3 days you are $\pm 10\ \frac 34$ of the time and $\pm 30$ the other $\frac 14$, for an expectation of $15$

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  If you assume the distribution of results is normal, it has a mean of $0$ and standard deviation of $\sigma=\sqrt {\frac 14\cdot 365}$.  Your result is then $2\int_0^\infty np(n) dn$ because the absolute value reflects the density below zero to above zero.  I believe it will scale with the square root of the number of trades.

Answer (score 0):

What is the starting amount of cash you enter the game with? Can you run bankrupt?
If 0 and no, then the final sum is also zero.

It is true for expectation of your cash position after any number of days (1 and 2 days including) as the expectation does not depend on number of iterations of this game.

Comment: From the statement, it seems unlikely that there is a concern for bankruptcy.  Note that OP asks for the expectation of the absolute value of the change, so it is greater than zero.

Comment: Ah, if "for 1 and 2 days, the answer works out to be 10" if it means the results of the trials we have on hands already then the expectation is 20 for the final change. This is a Markov chain with symmetrical probabilities - therefore the expectation of final position equals to the current position, expectation of a change is still 0 if counted from day 2. Isn't it?

Comment: You are still missing the point of the absolute value.  You are correct that the expectation of the final position is $0$.  If we ask for the absolute value of the final position it can't be less than $0$, and can be greater, so the expectation must be positive.  Roughly speaking, you expect to be $1\sigma $ away from $0$, so I would expect the answer to be around $\sigma$, but I haven't done the calculation.

Comment: well, the question is then what the OP means by "expected value of the absolute value of the amount of money". Just following the "expected value" I take the question as about the expectation. But even presuming the OP is interested in the variance, the question would be what confidence interval he wants to account for (just because the question strictly speaking is not about the variance).

Comment: I read it as  "expected value of (the absolute value of the amount of money)". You take a large number of tries, for each one take the absolute value of the outcome, and average them.  That is the desired result.  You are averaging a bunch of numbers, some zero, and the rest positive.  The result must be positive.

Comment: Agreed (also ConMan posted formula following your logic). Should be a prob with my english but I would define it as "expected amount of money changing hands in the game" :)

Comment: Yes, that is a good definition.

Answer (score 0):

Let $X_{n}$ be the amount of money you win after $n$ days. We know that $X_{n}$ follows a shifted, scaled binomial distribution (since it's basically just an adjusted count of the number of heads flipped), so we can approximate your winnings after a year as $X_{365} \sim \mathcal{N}(0, 100 \times 365 / 4) = \mathcal{N}(0, 9125)$ based on the variance of a binomial.

\begin{eqnarray}
E(|X_{365}|) & = & \int_x {|x| \cdot p(x) dx} \mbox{ where $x$ ranges over all possible amounts} \\
& = & \int_{x<0} {-x \cdot p(x) dx} + \int_{x \ge 0} {x \cdot p(x) dx} \\
& = & \int_{x \ge 0} x \cdot \left(p(x)+p(-x) \right) dx \\
& = & \int_{x \ge 0} 2x \cdot p(x) dx \mbox{ since p(x) is symmetrical} \\
& = & 2 \int_0^\infty x\cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{9125}\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2\times 9125}}dx \\
& = & \frac{2}{\sqrt{9125\times 2\pi}}\times\frac{1}{9125} \mbox{ left as an exercise}\\
& \approx & 9.15
\end{eqnarray}

In particular, noting that both of the 9125s come from the fact that after $n$ days, $\frac{X_n+n/2}{10} \sim Bin(n, 0.5)$ so that $E(X_n) = 0$ and $Var(X_n) = 100 n/4$, the expected value of the absolute value of your winnings/losses after $n$ days is given by $E(|X_n|) = \frac{2}{n^{3/2}\sqrt{2\pi}}$